# Необходимость именования функции содержащую в названии тип возвращаемой структуры данных

Tags: python, code-style

Стараюсь писать код так, чтобы при его чтении было понятно что происходит. Часто для понимания функции в местах его вызова нужно понимать тип структуры данных возвращаемой функцией, поэтому я придерживаюсь правила писать тип в имени функции.
Примеры таких имен:

```
get_tuple_of_tuples...
get_tuple_of_dicts...
```

и так далее. В декларации самих функций с помощью тайпинга указаны типы данных передаваемых параметров и тип структуры данных возвращаемой функцией.

Правильно ли я вообще поступаю, что в имени функции отражаю тип возвращаемой структуры? Если нет, то как правильно.

Comment: На эту тему есть [прекрасный доклад](https://youtu.be/z5WkDQVeYU4?t=1279) с Minsk Python Meetup. Мнение автора совпадает с моим — не стоит так делать. Это не несёт почти никакой пользы. К тому же в `Python` есть специальные средства для этого, о чём Вам и написали в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В именах функции лучше указать что описывают эти структуры.

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List

get_bananas(palms: List[Tuple]) -> Tuple[Tuple]:
    ''' Function get bananas from palms '''
...
get_oranges(trees: List[Dict]) -> Tuple[Dict]
    ''' Function get oranges from trees '''
...
```

Через какой тип питона они реализованны можно описать через `typing hints`. Важнее понять что нужно поместить в функцию и что выйдет из неё. Если получаем телефон пользователя - пишем `get_phone` а не `get_string` и не `get_phone_as_string`.

Используйте help строки для краткого, но подробного описания функций: что принимает, что возвращает или какие операции производит.